# AngularJS ng-repeat not re-rendering the repeater (UI) and not invoking ng-init once again

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, google-pie-chart

I have a small doubt about `ng-init`, actually I have some charts.

1. Trendline on top
2. Piecharts below.
3. HTML Table below.

on page load I am not displaying anything, but once I click on particular button for the first time then my entire charts and table is getting displayed for the data received by the http request. but afterwards if I click on the other button and executing same http request then its updating the trendline and table but not the piecharts. 
My piecharts are being rendered inside the below div with the ng-init, and when I am testing that ng-init="myFunction(index)" method its not updating on the subsequent click.

```
<form>
  <md-input-container>
    <label for="myInput">Search Division</label>
    <md-icon md-svg-icon="~/Content/myIcons/searchicon/ic_search_black_36px.svg"></md-icon>
    <input type="text" id="myInput" ng-model="searchDiv" md-autofocus>
  </md-input-container>
  <md-content ng-repeat="prod in listofProd | filter: searchDiv">
    <md-button class="md-whiteframe-1dp card" ng-click="generateChart(prod)" flex-sm="100" flex-gt-sm="100" flex-gt-md="100">
    {{prod}}
    </md-button>
  </md-content>
</form>

<div layout="row" layout-wrap>
  <div flex="25" style="width:1000px;height:300px; border: 1px solid skyblue;" ng-repeat="year in years track by $index" id="piechart{{$index}}" ng-init="myFunction($index)">
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is my angularjs code for the ng-init function.

```
(function () {
  'use strict'
  angular.module("GAiiNSApp").controller("ProdPerDash", ['$http', '$scope', '$log', function ($http, $scope, $log) {
    $scope.isLoading = false;
    $scope.hideme = true;
    var currentdate = new Date();
    var startdd = "01";
    var startmonth = "00";
    var lastyear = currentdate.getFullYear() - 3;
    var enddd = "31";
    var endmonth = "11";
    var endyear = currentdate.getFullYear();
    $scope.StartDate = new Date(lastyear, startmonth, startdd);
    $scope.EndDate = new Date(endyear, endmonth, enddd);
    $scope.Region = "Local";
    $scope.Country = "";
    $scope.ProductLineSelected = false;
    $scope.ButtonText = "CUSTOMIZE";

    $scope.clicked = false;
    $scope.Yes = function () {
      if (!$scope.clicked == true) {
        $scope.ButtonText = "CANCEL";
        $scope.clicked = true;
      }
      else {
        $scope.ButtonText = "CUSTOMIZE";
        $scope.clicked = false;
      }
    }
    $scope.alert = function (message) {
      $window.alert(message);
    }

    $scope.Regions = ["Export", "Local"];
    $http.get('/General/API/GetProductDivision').then(function (res) {
      $scope.listofProd = res.data;
    });
    $scope.selectedProduct = "";
    $scope.generateChart = function (prodname) {
      $scope.selectedProduct = prodname;
      $scope.isLoading = true;
      $http.get('/Marketing/MarketingAPI/ProdPerformance', {
        params: {
          StartDate: $scope.StartDate,
          EndDate: $scope.EndDate,
          ProductDivision: prodname,
          Division: $scope.Region,
          Area: $scope.Country
        }
      }).then(function (res) {
        var resArray = res.data;
        var trendarray = [];
        $scope.TableRecords = resArray;
        $scope.hideme = false;
        var json = resArray;
        // console.log("Array of Objects: " + JSON.stringify($scope.TableRecords));
        var groupedData = {};
        var result = [];
        resArray.forEach(function (item) {
          var year = item.SecuredYear;
          var value = item.ValueInDhs;
          if (groupedData.hasOwnProperty(year)) {
            groupedData[year] += value;
          } else {
            groupedData[year] = value;
          }
        });
        //Pie chart data starts here
        var years = [];
        json.forEach(function (obj) {
          if (years.indexOf(obj.SecuredYear) == -1)
            years.push(obj.SecuredYear);
        });
        //$scope.years = years;
        $scope.years = angular.copy(years);
        $scope.pichartsview = true;
        $scope.myFunction = function (index) {

          var data = [['Product', 'ValueInDhs']];
          json.forEach(function (obj) {
            if (obj.SecuredYear == years[index]) {
              data.push([String(obj.GroupName).trim(), obj.ValueInDhs]);
            }
          });
          $scope.displayChart(data, index);
        }
        $scope.displayChart = function (dataForChart, index) {
          var chartData = dataForChart;
          google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });
          google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChartPie);
          function drawChartPie() {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartData);
            var options = {
              chartArea: { left: 10, top: 20, width: "80%", height: "80%" },
              legend: 'bottom',
              is3D: true,
              pieSliceText: 'percentage',
              pieSliceTextStyle: {
                fontSize: 8
              },
              title: $scope.selectedProduct + " - " + $scope.years[index]
            };
            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart' + index));
            $scope.$apply(function () {
              chart.draw(data, options);
            });
          }
        }
        //Pie chart data ends here
        for (var year in groupedData) {
          var tmp = {};
          tmp[year] = groupedData[year];
          result.push(tmp);
        }
        result.forEach(function (obj, index) {
          var key = Object.keys(obj)[0];
          trendarray.push([parseInt(key, 10), obj[key]]);
        });
        trendarray.splice(0, 0, [{ label: 'SecuredYear', type: 'number' }, { label: 'ValueInDhs', type: 'number' }]);
        google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        $scope.isLoading = false;
          function drawChart() {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(
              trendarray
              );
            var options = {
              legend: 'none',
              title: 'Product Performance Trendline - ' + $scope.selectedProduct + " - " + $scope.Region,
              hAxis: { title: 'Secured Year', format: '0' },
              vAxis: { title: 'Secured Value in DHS' },
              trendlines: {
                0: {
                  lineWidth: 5,
                  type: 'polynomial',
                  visibleInLegend: true,
                  color: 'green',
                }
              }
            };
            var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div2'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
          }
        })
    $scope.ProductLineSelected = true;
    };
  }]); //this is ctrl closing
})(); //this is function closing
```

Comment: How do you bind the `ng-repeat` data `years`, one time or every time? Can you post the code for `onclick` event mentioned above?

Comment: every time I want to bind this years, and the years are binding properly I mean whenever I am clicking on button its calling the http and there its updating the years, but after that I have this myFunction its not running. I have just updated the code above with year functionality.

Comment: When you assign `$scope.years = years;`, just change this to `$scope.years = angular.copy(years);`. Just try this and I will update the answer shortly with the reason for this.

Comment: Ok. Let me change and check.

Comment: I just did update but its not changing the pie charts data.

Comment: can you update the full code of the controller?

Comment: just updated the full code of the controller.

Comment: okay, I will have a look

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130117/discussion-between-saleem-and-aruna).

Comment: **Aruna**, Can I expect an answer here.

Comment: I will look at it today.

Comment: **Aruna**, did you get the issue.

Comment: **Aruna**, are we going to discuss about this today.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130295/discussion-between-aruna-and-saleem).

Answer (score 1):

> Since `Angular 1.2`, it has an option `track by` to prevent the repeater
>   from re-rendering all the items to improve the performance.

More information can be found at: http://www.codelord.net/2014/04/15/improving-ng-repeat-performance-with-track-by/

That's why `ng-init` is not fired again for the same `years` rendered already since you have used the `track by` here `ng-repeat="year in years track by $index"`.

Even if you remove this, the `ng-init` is again not fired for the second time since `years` here is the array where `Angular` is brilliant enough to track by its value though there is no explicit `track by`.

Hence, we have to change the `years` from simple array to `object array` like, `[{year: obj.SecuredYear}]` to let Angular to generate a `$$hashKey` which is not identical when the object changed every time and Angular will redraw the repeater by firing `ng-init`.

So the changes related to this are,

**Html**

```
<div flex="25" style="width:1000px;height:300px; border: 1px solid skyblue;" 
  ng-repeat="year in years" id="piechart{{$index}}" ng-init="myFunction($index)">
</div>
```

**JS** (populating `years`)

```
    var years = [];
    json.forEach(function (obj) {
      var exists = years.filter(function(y) {
        return y.year === obj.SecuredYear;
      });

      if (exists.length === 0) { // This will replace the `indexOf` check
        years.push({year: obj.SecuredYear});  // change here
      }
    });
    $scope.years = years;
```

**JS** (myFunction())

```
      $scope.myFunction = function (index) {
      var data = [['Product', 'ValueInDhs']];
      json.forEach(function (obj) {
        if (obj.SecuredYear == years[index].year) {   // change here at years[index].year
          data.push([String(obj.GroupName).trim(), obj.ValueInDhs]);
        }
      });
      $scope.displayChart(data, index);
    };
```

I just created a sample *snippet* as below to check this with a `console.log(years[index].year);` inside the `$scope.myFunction()` which logs successfully with `ng-init`, every time the button `Generate Chart` is clicked.

```js
angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    var json = [{SecuredYear: 1965},{SecuredYear: 1988}, {SecuredYear: 2016}, {SecuredYear: 2012}];
    $scope.generateChart = function(item) {
      
        var years = [];
        json.forEach(function (obj) {
          var exists = years.filter(function(y) {
            return y.year === obj.SecuredYear;
          });
          
          if (exists.length === 0) {
            years.push({year: obj.SecuredYear});
          }
        });
        $scope.years = years;
      
        
        $scope.myFunction = function (index) {
          var data = [['Product', 'ValueInDhs']];
          json.forEach(function (obj) {
            if (obj.SecuredYear == years[index].year) {
              //data.push([String(obj.GroupName).trim(), obj.ValueInDhs]);
              console.log(years[index].year);
            }
          });
          //$scope.displayChart(data, index);
        };
    };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <button ng-click="generateChart()">Generate Chart</button><br/>
        <div style="border: 1px solid skyblue;" ng-repeat="year in years" id="piechart{{$index}}" ng-init="myFunction($index)" >{{year.year}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: **Aruna**, all of a sudden it started giving error on another part of the draw chart function. The error is **Error: $rootScope:inprog**. The charts are being rendered properly for the first time, but once I click for second time on the button then it give the above error.

Comment: @Saleem Can you gimme the full error and there will be a angular url with the error which you can gimme as well. I will have a look.

Comment: **Aruna**, this is the link for the error. **https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog?p0=$digest** the error is coming inside the **$scope.displayChart = function (dataForChart, index) {** function. you can have the TeamViewer if you want.

Comment: okay, this is because of this line inside the `$scope.displayChart` function, `$scope.$apply(function () {
              chart.draw(data, options);
            });`. You can remove the `$scope.$apply(function () { })` wrapper and you can change this line simply to `chart.draw(data, options);`.

Comment: So change from `$scope.$apply(function () { chart.draw(data, options); });` to `chart.draw(data, options);`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130371/discussion-between-saleem-and-aruna).

Comment: **Aruna**, Can we discuss about the issue now?

Comment: **Aruna**, did you get the solution.

Comment: Can anybody attempt this question?

Answer (score 0):

```js
angular.module('app', [
    'googlechart'
  ])
  .controller('appCtrl', function() {
    let vm = this;
    vm.charts = [];

    vm.addChart = function() {
      vm.charts.push({
        type: "PieChart",
        data: {
          "cols": [{
            id: "t",
            label: "Topping",
            type: "string"
          }, {
            id: "s",
            label: "Slices",
            type: "number"
          }],
          "rows": [{
            c: [{
              v: "Mushrooms"
            }, {
              v: 3
            }, ]
          }, {
            c: [{
              v: vm.input.name
            }, {
              v: vm.input.quantity
            }]
          }, {
            c: [{
              v: "Olives"
            }, {
              v: 31
            }]
          }, {
            c: [{
              v: "Zucchini"
            }, {
              v: 1
            }, ]
          }, {
            c: [{
              v: "Pepperoni"
            }, {
              v: 2
            }, ]
          }]
        }
      });
    };
    return vm;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-google-chart/0.1.0/ng-google-chart.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="appCtrl as vm">
  <div ng-repeat="chart in vm.charts track by $index">
    <div google-chart chart="chart" style="height:150px; width:100%;"></div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <input type="text" required ng-model="vm.input.name" placeholder="Enter name">
  <input type="number" required ng-model="vm.input.quantity" placeholder="Enter quantity">
  <button ng-click="vm.addChart()">Add chart</button>
</div>
```

I've noticed you're using google charts. Your problem derives from using a non-compatible library (google charts is unaware of the changes in the model - angular in that case).

You **could** write your own directive but why do that if someone else already did the heavy lifting? Instead I suggest you consider using the following [directive](https://github.com/angular-google-chart/angular-google-chart).

Here's a [live](http://angular-google-chart.github.io/angular-google-chart/docs/latest/examples/pie/) example.

Edit: `ng-init` does **not** work the way you want it to. `ng-init` simply fires a function when the **controller** loads, not when the element is being rendered.

Comment: I have no idea about using the anguarjs charts can you show me an example using my code:)

Comment: There's a whole site dedicated to examples. use the links I provided.

Comment: **Muli**, as you can see I am trying to display pie charts under ng-repeat, with angular charts not getting how to accomplish the same. appreciate if you could help me out here.

Comment: Ok. so how do I render multiple pie chart dynamically?

Comment: I'll post a minimal example. please note this will be minimal and you will have to learn how to use the directive.

Comment: sure please. but include the ng-init or alternate method.

Comment: **Muli**, did you get the solution?

Comment: **Muli**, Hi there, did you get any solution.

Comment: Saleem I already posted an example. If you want me to fix your code that's not gonna happen.